# MutableLiveData not posting value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mutablelivedata

I'm trying to post a state as "Loading" to display a progress bar to the user while downloading data from the server, it looks like this:

```
private fun loadBottomSheetItems(currentViewState: BusinessMapViewState.Display, getBusinessByIdsRequest: GetBusinessByIdsRequest) {
 
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _businessMapViewState.postValue(
            currentViewState.copy(
                bottomSheetState = BottomSheetViewState.Loading <--------------- Always that state!
            )
        )
 
        val responseFlow = businessRepository.getBusinessListByIds(
            getBusinessByIdsRequest
        )
 
        responseFlow.collect { result ->
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                val businesses = result.asSuccess().value.businessList
 
                _businessMapViewState.postValue(
                    currentViewState.copy(
                        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetViewState.Display(
                            items = businesses.map { business ->
                                BusinessListCardItemModel(
                                    businessId = business.id,
                                    businessName = business.name
                                )
                            }
                        )
                    )
                )
            } else {
                _businessMapViewState.postValue(
                    currentViewState.copy(
                        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetViewState.Error
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I post the "Loading" state, that state doesn't change after the data is loaded.

If I remove the postValue block for the "Loading" state, or add a delay, the data displays correctly, but I need a progress bar.

I also tried to move the postValue block for the "Loading" state outside the viewModelScope, nothing changes

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem, the other part of my code was changing the state of ui

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use `postValue` if you need things to happen orderly. “Post” means ”do this sometime soon” and causes the value to be changed at some later time while the coroutine is still running. It will necessarily happen sometime after your coroutine relinquishes the main thread.

Use `value =` instead. This is fine because `viewModelScope` is on Dispatchers.Main.

Comment: I tried using "value" and unfortunately that doesn't work either, I still get the infinite "loading"

Comment: Are you sure you’re collecting a successful result?

Comment: yes, I watched on the debugger and also removed the "Loading" state, the data comes in correctly

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04, Can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75367786/8266651).